# Strange behavior in AspNetCore API Route

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-code-500

So, guys I have a route in my API that receives a JSON than it is treated and sended back.

What is wrong with that? Nothing.

But has a strange behavior that sometimes I send a json document and receive error 500 with the message "An unxpected erro occurred" but If I send it again (without change nothing) then it works;

Please guys, can you help me telling me how can I catch an exception for this, if there is one.

This is the code that receives the request:

```
public async Task<string> SaveHumanChat(JObject talk)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState).ToString();

            var conversa = talk.ToString();
            try
            {
                return await _service.SaveHumanChat(conversa);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
```

Ps: I've tried to use ArgumentException but without success.

Comment: I suggest in the first instance you check your logs for exceptions when the HTTP 500 occurs. It might be coming from a different part of the ASP.NET Core request pipeline and not from your controller.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to check there. Thanks.